# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') in react js while using redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, e-commerce, use-effect

My backend works perfectly fine, even my redux integration with react js work completely fine but as soon as i use useEffect it gives an error of "Cannot read properties of undefined"
[image: This is the error being shown]

Below is my code:

```
const ProductListScreen = ({ match }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const shopDetails = useSelector((state) => state.shopDetails)
  const { loading, error, shop } = shopDetails

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(shopDetail(match.params.shopid))
  }, [dispatch, match])

  if (loading) {
    return (
      <div className='loader'>
        <Loader />
      </div>
    )
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Link className='btn btn-dark my-3' to='/'>
        Go Back
      </Link>
      <h3>{shop.name} Products</h3>
      {error ? (
        <Message variant='warning' color='red'>
          {error}
        </Message>
      ) : (
        <Row>
          {shop &&
            shop.products.map((product) => (
              <Col key={product._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
                <Product product={product} shopId={shop._id} />
              </Col>
            ))}
        </Row>
      )}
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: console.log(shop.products) //see if its an array and has any data

Comment: it shows undefined when i do so, but when comment out useEffect and then console log the output, then it works just fine :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Row>
      {shop &&
        shop.products?.map((product) => (
          <Col key={product._id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
            <Product product={product} shopId={shop._id} />
          </Col>
        ))}
    </Row>
```

Use the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) in order to skip map of undefined products

Pretty sure, shop it's truthy, so the condition is true, but still you are not checking the truthiness of products when mapping through it

Comment: Thanks a lot man! that worked for me.